# Unable to send email in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, smtp

I'm using the official [Yii2 documentation for sending emails](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/656/how-to-send-emails-using-smtp), I have also checked several tutorials and StackOverflow answers but I don't understand the error.

I wish to send an email for users to click through to set up a new password when they forget the current one.

Following the guide in the document I have set up the config

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'htmlLayout' =>  '@app/mail/layouts/html',
            // 'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            //'useFileTransport' => true,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'app_password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
            'streamOptions' => [ 'ssl' => [ 
                'allow_self_signed' => true,                         
                'verify_peer' => false,                         
                'verify_peer_name' => false,                     
                ],
            ],
```

and the controller

```
public function actionForgot()
    {
            
        if(isset($_POST['Lupa']))
        {
            $getEmail=$_POST['Lupa']['email'];

            $getModel= Users::findOne(['email' => $getEmail]);
            // User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$getEmail));
            $getToken=rand(0, 99999);
            $getTime=date("H:i:s");
            // $getModel->token=md5($getToken.$getTime);
            $org="Some Team";
            $emailadmin="admin_email";
            $subjek="Reset Password";
            $setpesan="you have successfully reset your password<br/>
                <a href='http://localhost:8080/site/forgot?r=site/vertoken/view&token='>Click Here to Reset Password</a>";
                // ".$getModel->token."
            
            if(!$getModel) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Please fill in an registered email');
                // return Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Url::to(['site/login']));
            }
            else if($getModel->validate())
                {
                    $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($org).'?=';
                    $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subjek).'?=';
                    $headers="From: $name <{$emailadmin}>\r\n".
                        "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                        "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
                    $getModel->save();
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('forgot','link to reset your password has been sent to your email');
                    mail($getEmail,$subject,$setpesan,$headers);
                    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    // $type, ['data' => $data]
                        ->setFrom($emailadmin)
                        ->setTo($getEmail)
                        ->setSubject($subjek)
                        ->send();
                    $this->refresh();
                }
            
        }
        $this->layout = 'forgot';
        return $this->render('forgot');
    }
```

When I send the form, this is the error I get on the console

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMran.png)

And this is the code snippet that causes the error

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'forgot-form',
                        'enableClientValidation'=>false,
                        'validateOnSubmit' => true, 
                    ]); ?>
```

It's from the view file

Could you please help?

Comment: Do you have anything in your `app.log` file?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco no I don't

Comment: Why do you have both `mail()` call and Yii2's compose & send in your code?

Comment: What the error you see during sending email? Could you share it? Or wrap your code with try-catch block and dump exception in catch block.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An example can be found here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/PasswordResetRequestForm.php

Comment: Port 587 is normally used for tls. Try to set the port to 465, which is used for ssl.

Comment: Hello @MichalHynčica I used both just to test

Comment: @Viktor I have updated my question to include the error I see on the console

Comment: @ivion I have done that. Nothing has changed